# SigninActivity is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to change the activity on "`onPostExecute`" but it doesn't seem to work even though it works on other activities.

Here's my code:

```
public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private TextView statusField,roleField;
    private Context context;
    private int byGetOrPost = 0;

    public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,TextView roleField,int flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusField = statusField;
        this.roleField = roleField;
        byGetOrPost = flag;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        if(byGetOrPost == 0){ 

            try{
                String username = (String)arg0[0];
                String password = (String)arg0[1];
                String link = "http://website/login.php?username="+username+"& password="+password;

                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                in.close();
                return sb.toString();
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                String username = (String)arg0[0];
                String password = (String)arg0[1];

                String link="http://website.com/login.php";
                String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.write( data );
                wr.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(SigninActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if someone tells me where I'm wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing mistake in your `onPostExecute(String result)` method.
Replace

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(SigninActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent3);
```

By

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
```